# Retrofit execute method is it background task

Tags: android, http, retrofit

Is Retrofit `.execute` method is already background task or should I call this method in `AsyncTask` in retrofit official documentation it mentions that callbacks executed in mainThread, but its not clear if execute method is background task.

Retrofit documentation:

> SYNCHRONOUS VS. ASYNCHRONOUS
>   Call instances can be executed either synchronously or asynchronously. Each instance can only be used once, but calling clone() will create a new instance that can be used.
>
> On Android, callbacks will be executed on the main thread. On the JVM,
>   callbacks will happen on the same thread that executed the HTTP
>   request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
call.execute() //not a background task, works in the foreground(synchronous).
call.enqueue() //This is a background task(asynchronous).
```

`call.execute()` runs the request on the current thread.
`call.enqueue()` runs the request on a background thread, and runs the callback on the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests) has a nice explanation on what you are asking for. In short Asynchronous requests will have callbacks like `onResponse` and `onFailure`. If you are making request to API, you would certainly want to go with asynchronous.